# How do I get a custom-printed helmet?

Tags: helmets

I've found a few places that will put a logo on a helmet (e.g., [here](http://www.helmetsrus.net/nonprofit/info_pages.php?pages_id=13)), but I haven't found anywhere that will let you fully design the art on the helmet, produce it, and ship it to you. I'm interested in this for some corporate swag. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's "logo" (an abbreviation of "logogram" or "logotype"), not "log".

Comment: I think "printed" is less ambiguous than "designed" in the title, given the history of odd-shaped bicycle helmets

Comment: We don't do product recommendations because they go stale pretty quick.  Service recommendations should hang around longer, but will also go stale with time.  Recommend to close as off topic.

Comment: @Criggie would it still be off-topic if the focus were changed for "what sort of service should I be searching for to find someone to obtain..." ?

Comment: @james I'm not worried - seems to be a popular question with 6 upvotes, and that's what counts.  If you do go ahead with this, please post an update answer with photos showing what you did and how it worked for you, and then a follow-on after a couple months of usage of the new helmet, for closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technology is called hydro dipping or water transfer printing. A quick search will find several companies that do it. I would expect you can find one that handles the production and shipping when you provide the design.

Comment: Also known as hydrographics printing or immersion printing. You can find videos of it on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beV3dAW-u_M. I suspect it doesn't affect the safety on helmets, but I'm not sure with the chemicals involved. That being said, a lot of people use it on motorcycle helmets.

Comment: Both of my helmets have graphics that can only be hydro dipped at factory. So I guess safe chemicals at least exist.